# Quantity selection disappeared from Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a Woocommerce enabled site and fiddling around with it.

Since yesterday, after trying to modify some php script (then restored to its original form) the **quantity box** and **+/- buttons** totally disappeared from any product.

Even a new product with no options cannot be purchased in multiple quantities...In th esingle product page, in cart....

I didn't touch any Woocommerce option (at least not intentionally), and I didn't set the "allow to be sold individually" anywhere...

How could I verify if quantity box is enabled or not globally?

Comment: Deactivate and Delete the woocommerce once then re-install and check it again.

Comment: what the hell! I updated the plugin (I believe I did last update yesterday) and now the quantity button is back.... !!!!

Comment: Ha, ha... by mistake some files were modified from WooCommerce..now its back after update..